# Shortest time required UART- UART transfer of 32 Byte block

Tags: uart, microprocessor, quartus-ii, time

I need to transfer 32 Byte block UART to UART 
8 clock cycles per bit
1 start bit
Struct 8-E-2 8bits 1 UART char, Even Parity, 2 stop bits/ char

1 + 8 + Even parity + 2 stop bits = 11

efficiency = 8/11 (not sure)

Can any one help me the calculate the shortest time required to transfer?

Assume Micro Controller with 16MHz clock needs to transfer 32 Bytes of data

Comment: How fast can your UART clock be?

Comment: 1 + 8 + parity (1) + 2 stop bits =1 12 bits. 12 bits x 32 = 384 bits. Time = 112 / bit rate (per second). You didn't mention your bps rate, so there's no way to calculate the answer.

Comment: What microcontroller or other device are you using?

Comment: quartus II microcontroller

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 8x - 16x

Comment: No, that's the prescaler ratio.

Comment: Hmm ok its not specified

Comment: @Randy baud rate is standard RS-232

Comment: I Edited my question now added a line

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 16MHz clock

Comment: Quartus II is design software, not a microcontroller.

Comment: An additional, likely major issue you are overlooking is that of how your systems are to agree which byte begins a 32-byte message.  You'll need something like timegaps, special codes that can't occur inside a message, or an additional signal (hopefully not the board reset!)

Comment: Hopefully you've gotten your answers by now, but just to follow up, there is no ONE baud rates for RS232. there are many standard baud rates, typically 300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 57.6K and 119.2K, to name some. Obviously the higher the baud rate you can work with, the faster the transfer.  Also, the clock speed in itself does not tell you the baud rate, as it is typically divided down by a large factor within the UART. So if you don't specifically know the baud rate, you'll have to either use a scope as someone already suggested, or use a terminal program and try to recognize the data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: In many scenarios which enable parity, it may may used for frame marking. For example, if one uses even parity for data and uses an odd-parity 0x80 as a start-of-data indicator and on odd-parity 0xFF as end-of-data, no framing error in a packet could cause packet data to be misinterpreted as a start-of-packet, and any framing error within a packet would get resolved by the next start-of-packet indicator.

Answer (score 3):

Time required would be 32 bytes * 12 bits/byte divided by the baud rate.  (1 start bit + 8 data bits + 1 parity bit + 2 stop bits = 12 bits).  The baud rate is the 'bit clock' that determines how long the bits are.  A standard baud rate is 115200 bits per second.  This may or may not be the baud rate you're using.  Other standard baud rates are 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, and 38400.  If the baud rate is 115200, then the time required to transmit 32 bytes is 32 * 12 / 115200 = 3.33 ms.

Comment: Why is parity bit 1 since in the question its mentioned even parity bit

Comment: The parity bit is an extra bit that is transmitted along with the data.  If you send data 01000101 with an even parity bit, one start bit, and two stop bits, you will actually send 0 01000101 1 11, which is 12 bits in total.  Even parity means that if you count up all the 1s in the parity and data, then you get an even number unless a bit got flipped in transit (01000101 1 has 4 ones).

Comment: I got it thanks a ton. How should i confirm the baud rate?

Comment: Measure it with an oscilloscope?  I have no idea without a lot more information about your device.  Generally devices have a baud rate generator (usually little more than a digital divider, though they can use a fractional divider) and by looking at the baud rate generator settings and device clock, you can figure out the baud rate.

Comment: baud rate = (payload bit rate * packet size)/char size.that is 12 * 32 / 8bit(1 uart data char)

Comment: baud rate = symbols / second.  In this case, 1 symbol = 1 bit so baud rate = bits / second.  Now, this baud rate is not data bits per second, the data rate will actually be baud rate * data bits / (data + overhead) or baud rate * 8/12.

Comment: so is 115200 is rite according to calculation?

Comment: No.  There is insufficient information.  It is not possible to calculate the baud rate from the information that you have provided.  2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, and 115200 are all standard RS232 baud rates, but I have no idea which one you might be using without more information about the device it is running on.  For example, see page 179 of http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf .  This is how to calculate the baud rate for an Atmel ATMEGA328P microcontroller.  It is entirely dependent on the configuration of the device, and you have not even mentioned what device you are using.

Comment: Cyclone II EP2C35F672C6

Comment: Alright, an FPGA does not have a UART in it unless you instantiate some sort of UART IP.  What UART are you using?

Comment: nios uart we are using

Comment: I take it you are trying to connect two Cyclone II FPGAs together?  Is this an existing design or a new design?  Is there a particular reason that you have to use a UART?  A protocol like SPI might be a better idea - it is very simple to implement and can run much faster as it is synchronous, but it requires more pins.

Comment: hmm I get it, So the baud rate would be 115200 rite?

Comment: If you are designing this from scratch, the baud rate is whatever you want it to be.  You might even be able to get away with 1 Mbit/sec or more.

Comment: its a part of assignment they havent specified anything

Comment: baud rate = avalon clock cycle / divisor +1

Comment: That's much better - if you know the clock rate and divisor, then you have the baud rate.

Comment: I am ot sure what is divisor, but clock rate would be 8(clock rate per bits)

Comment: So its 8 clock per bit, 16 bit integer divisor

Comment: Do you think 15.05 sounds rite 256/16+1

Comment: Your question says the clock rate is 16 MHz, and 8 bits per clock.  So I would presume the bit rate is 2 M bits/sec.

Comment: baud rate will be 2 x 10^6 rite?

Comment: Sorry it says 8 clock cycle per bit

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant - 8 clocks per bit, for 16 MHz / 8 = 2 Mbps.  In some cases, you can get more than one bit per system clock, e.g. serial gigabit ethernet (used over fiber, wired gigabit ethernet uses a very different protocol) generally runs the logic at 125 MHz, but then has a 1:10 serdes so the link rate is actually 1.25 Gbps.  One way to implement this is to use a PLL to generate a 12.5 GHz bit clock or 6.25 GHz DDR bit clock so it can transfer 10 bits serially in each system clock cycle.

Comment: Just a little confusion isnt it 16 / 8+ 1 ?

Comment: Seems like they are getting at 16 MHz / (7 + 1)

Comment: got it, now it makes sense. 32 * 12 / 2097152 = 0.183105ms? Thank you so much for your support i guess I got my concept straight

Comment: do you think my answer is correct?

Comment: Where are you getting 2097152 from?

Comment: when i convert 2 mbps in bits?

Comment: 2 Mbps is just 2 x 10^6 bps.  The only time 2^10 (or 2^20) is used instead of 10^3 (or 10^6) is when measuring memory sizes.  For example, gigabit ethernet is 1x10^9 bits per second, not 1x2^30.  A 1G DRAM, on the other hand, would be 1x2^30 bits because this is the addressable range you get with 30 address lines (not that these chips have 30 physical address pins, you get 30 address bits from a combination of row select, column select, and bank select inputs).

Comment: what do you think is the correct answer?

Comment: This seems like a homework problem; and you have all of the pieces at this point.  I'm not going to give you the answer outright.